# what is the difference between the time of android animatorSet and the animation time it contains?

Tags: android, animation, timing

I have a animatorSet with x animations playing together, i don't understand the deference between the time in animationSet.setDuration(**duration**) and the time in Glider.glide(easing, **duration**, objAnimation());

what's the difference? please.

code sample:

```
public View doAddItemAnimation(View view, int delay) {

    view.setAlpha(0);

    AnimatorSet doAddItemAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
    doAddItemAnimation.playTogether(
            Glider.glide(Skill.Linear, duration * 3, ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 0.2f, 1)),
            Glider.glide(Skill.ExpoEaseOut,duration * 1.5f, ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 0.3f, 1)),
            Glider.glide(Skill.ExpoEaseInOut, duration * 1.5f, ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 0.3f, 1)),

            Glider.glide(Skill.ExpoEaseOut, duration * 2, ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", 500, 0))
    );

    doAddItemAnimation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

        }
    });

    doAddItemAnimation
            .setDuration(duration * 3)
            .setStartDelay(delay);
    doAddItemAnimation.start();

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Looking at the source code it seems both durations should be same i.e Glide duration is used for calculating interpolation while AnimatorSet duration is the actual timing duration ; https://github.com/daimajia/AnimationEasingFunctions/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/daimajia/easing/BaseEasingMethod.java .

Comment: but should be the same, on what grounds must report all times?

Comment: If I understand the code correctly Glider duration is stored as an internal variable to be used during the animation. While AnimationSet duration is the actual duration animation will last. Now if these durations differ it is possible Glide interpolation over- or underflows giving unexpected results. But this should be clearly visible if you face such behavior, I'm just trying to inerpret the code and could be wrong.

Comment: I tried many times and the value seems to be respected is the duration the animatorSet, confused.